# Why is this object drawn different if I use glFrustum?

Tags: opengl, glfrustum

I'm doing this OpenGL project for my Computer Graphics class, where I display an object and I rotate it and stuff, the thing is that at the beginning of the project we used `glOrtho()` and it looked really great.

[image: glOrthoOBJ]

But now the teacher said that we have to use `glFrustum()` for perspective and if I use that function, the object is drawn like this and I really don't know why does this happens:

[image: glFrustumOBJ]

This is my code from the `init()` function where everything changes:

```
void init (void)
{
    /*  select clearing (background) color       */
    glClearColor (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-100.0, 100.0, -60.0, 160.0, -100.0, 100.0);
    //glFrustum(-100, 100 ,-100 ,100 ,1 , 40);


    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glRotatef(90,0,1,0);
}
```

I'd appreciate your help.

EDIT: If I use glFrustum(-100, 100, -100, 100, 20, 200) it looks like this, like I'm getting closer but what about the left, right, top and bottom parameters? Are they okay with that values?

[image]

Comment: Try for closer near to far ratio, you'll get closer result to orthographic projection. Try for example glFrustum(-100, 100 ,-100 ,100 , 20, 150). 40 to 1 is extreme.

Comment: @Victor: the `far/near` ratio does in no way make a perspective projection closer to an orthonognal one, nor is a 40:1 ratio "extreme" in any way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain without more information. Perhaps the model could give some insight. But I suspect it may have to do with your clipping planes (`nearVal` and `farVal` as described [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glFrustum.xml)) arguments passed to `glFrustum` (`1, 40`). Perhaps try setting them to a broader range like your `glOrtho` call: `1, 150` (Note: neither `nearVal` or `farVal` can be negative when passed to `glFrustum`).

This all depends on the scale of the model and how it is positioned relative to the camera. If part of the model falls outside of the clipping planes, then it will be, well... clipped.